# How to use output of Neural Network as input for another NN in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I implemented an LSTM with Keras and trained it on a corpus. Now I want to take the output of the NN and pass it as input to another NN model and test on a test set. I saved the model of the NN, but I do not know how to extract the output and feed it to the other NN. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=
['accuracy'])
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=500)
# save the model to file
model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'output' here? I don't see outputting anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any need to save a model to extract output . You can simply use the `predict()`function to get your output.
In your case to get the output from your model pass the test input as shown

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

where X_test is your test input and 'prediction' will contain your output which can then be printed.

For giving this output as input to another model , first create another model like you have one and then pass the prediction variable into the `model.fit()` function.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! And how can I then use the prediction as input to another model?

Answer (score 0):

To use the output of one model in another model, simply load it and use it:

```
m0 = tf.keras.models.load_model("path_to_model_here", compile=False)
m0 = m0(some_input)

m1 = concatenate([some_input, m0])
m1 = Dense(DENSE_LAYER_NEURONS, input_shape=(INPUT_SIZE + M0_SIZE,), activation="relu")(m1)
m1 = Dense(DENSE_LAYER_NEURONS, activation="relu")(m1)
...
```